# SectionList how to wrap items in a section

Tags: react-native, expo

I've currently got a `SectionList`. I'd like to wrap all items within a section in a `FlatList`. e.g. For the section `Queues Near You`, The three `RestaurantCard`s of Tonkotsu, Burgerville and Fried Fries should be in a `FlatList` that is horizontal, Restaraunt A,B,C should be in its own `FlatList`, etc. How can I achieve this?

```
const sectionData = [
  {
    title: "Queues Near You",
    data: ["Tonkotsu", "BurgerVille", "Fried Fries"],
  },
  {
    title: "Restaurants Near You",
    data: ["Restaurant A", "Restaurant B", "Resto C"],
  },
  {
    title: "Additional Places Near You",
    data: ["Resto D", "Resto E", "Resto F"],
  },
];
```

```
export default function App() {

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    const restaurantName = item
    return <RestaurantCard restaurantName={restaurantName} />;
  };

  return (
    <View style={tw`flex-1 bg-black`}>
        <SectionList
          sections={sectionData}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => {
            return <SubHeader style={tw`flex-grow-0`} name={title} />
          }}
          renderItem={renderItem}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up just forcing `SectionList` to iterate over the sections by having the section be the single object in the `data` array, and just render a `FlatList` for every section

```
const sectionData= [
  {
    title: "Queues Near You",
    data: [{ restaurants: ["Tonkotsu", "BurgerVille", "Fried Fries"] }],
  },
  {
    title: "Restaurants Near You",
    data: [{ restaurants: ["Tonkotsu", "BurgerVille", "Fried Fries"] }],
  },
  {
    title: "Additional Places Near You",
    data: [{ restaurants: ["Tonkotsu", "BurgerVille", "Fried Fries"] }],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the same array, you can use nested FlatList like below.

```
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
      return (
          <View>
              <FlatList
               horizontal
               data={item}
               renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
               return (
                   <View>
                       //your UI code
                   </View>)
               }}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              />
        </View>);
    }}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking more so for a solution with SectionList tho since it seems more semantically sound. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can add horizontal scroll view as parent of RestaurantCard component
export default function App() {

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
const restaurantName = item
return (



);
};
return (

<SectionList
sections={sectionData}
renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => {
return <SubHeader style={tw`flex-grow-0`} name={title} />
}}
renderItem={renderItem}
/>

);
}